# Snowflake copy into command regex pattern - ignore the case

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a snow pipe that auto ingest data files that are posted in an azure storage container.

The pipe is defined as

```
create pipe PIPE_NAME
auto_ingest = true
integration = 'STG_NI_DATAWAREHOUSE_FILES'
as
copy into STAGE_ORDER(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
from
(
  select t.$1,t.$2,t.$3
  from @STG_AZURE_STAGE_DATA_WAREHOUSE_FILES t
)
pattern = 'Allturna_Client_Orders_.*txt'
ON_ERROR=CONTINUE
file_format=(format_name = 'STG_FILE_FORMAT_DATA_WAREHOUSE_UTF16');
```

The files are auto ingested correctly as long as the file name case matches the one in the pattern. If the file being posted is allturna_client_orders_1.txt or ALLTURNA_CLIENT_ORDERS_1.TXT the files do not post. Based on regex if i create a pattern in the create pipe definition as /Allturna_JNJ_Orders_.*txt/i that does not work.

How can i resolve this?

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0):

This is a regex that would match both your filenames:

```
(?i)\bAllturna_Client_Orders_.*txt\b
```

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/hXMtaL/1).